# How to read a string from a cmd output and return the value in a batch script?

Tags: powershell, batch, cmd.exe

My Windows server is connected to a remote office network through two default gateways.

##### Default Gateways

```
172.20.0.1    Primary
172.20.0.254  Secondary

// Secondary connected with
// 4G SIM card VPN
```

##### Server's Initial Configuration

```
172.20.0.10   IP Address
255.255.255.0 Subnet Mask
172.20.0.1    Default Gateway
```

I want to run a batch script on the server that detects when the primary gateway `172.20.0.1` fails and automatically switches the server to the secondary gateway `172.20.0.254` and vice versa.

I want to detect the failure by regularly pinging the current gateway.

```
Pinging 172.20.105.1 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 172.20.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255

Reply from 172.20.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255

Reply from 172.20.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255
```

When the ping fails it doesn't return "TTL=" and the script would assume the gateway is down and change to the other Gateway.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

:loop
ping 172.20.0.1 -n 2
timeout /t 10
set "str1=%~1"

if not "%str1:"TTL="=%" == "%str1%" (
     echo "Primary Gateway NOT reachable"
     netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" static 172.20.0.10 255.255.255.0 172.20.0.254   
    )

echo "Primary Data UP"
goto loop
```

Is there a  better way to do this server-side?

Comment: So what isn't working in your script?  and FYI - you can use the for command to execute a command and read the results. From the help: `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]`

Comment: Well, you did mention Powershell as a tag. So to the question "is there a better way", the answer will usually be "yes, do it in Powershell". In this case, consider `if (Test-Connection -TargetName Server01 -Quiet) {<dosomething>}`. No text scraping involved...

Answer (score 2):

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_gtw#254=netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" static 172.20.0.10 255.255.255.0 172.20.0.254"
set "_gtw#001=!_gtw#254:172.20.0.254=172.20.0.1!"
set "_msg#001=Primary Gateway NOT reachable"
set "_msg#002=Primary Data UP"

mode.com con: cols=60 lines=5
for /f tokens^=1*delims^=#skip^=4 %%i in ('echo;prompt $E#$H^|cmd.exe
    ')do set "_$E=%%~i" & set "_bs=%%~j"

%:^)
title <nul
set "_dns=" <nul
echo/!_$E![1F!_$E![0J

for /f tokens^=2*delims^=: %%i in ('netsh interface ipv4 show config ^| findstr "DNS.*DHCP.*[0-9]"
   ')do for /f %%n in ('%ComSpec% /u /c echo="%%~i"^<nul ^| find /v " "')do set "_dns=!_dns!%%~n"

title Gateway: !_dns!
echo/!_bs!!_$E![1;33m Please^^! Wait for few seconds...!_$E![0m

ping !_dns! -n 6 -w 500 | find /c "TTL" | find "6" >nul && goto %:^) || =;(
     if "!_dns!" == "172.20.0.1" 2>nul =;(
           echo; !_msg#001!
           !_gtw#254!
           echo; !_msg#002:Primary=Secondary!
        ); else 2>nul =;( 
           echo; !_msg#001:Primary=Secondary!
           !_gtw#001!
           echo; !_msg#002!
        );=
    );= 

timeout /t 00010 /nobreak >nul 
echo/!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E!
goto %:^)
```

---

Or...

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_gtw#254=static 172.20.0.10 255.255.255.0 172.20.0.254"
set "_msg#001=Primary Gateway NOT reachable" 
set "_msg#002=Primary Data UP"

set "_gtw#254=netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" !_gtw#254!"
set "_gtw#001=!_gtw#254:172.20.0.254=172.20.0.1!"

for /f tokens^=1*delims^=#skip^=4 %%i in ('echo;prompt $E#$H^|cmd.exe
    ')do set "_$E=%%~i" & set "_bs=%%~j" & mode.com con: cols=60 lines=5

%:^)
title <nul & set "_dns=" <nul & echo/!_$E![1F!_$E![0J

for /f tokens^=2*delims^=: %%i in ('netsh interface ipv4 show config ^| findstr "DNS.*DHCP.*[0-9]"
   ')do for /f %%n in ('%ComSpec% /u /c echo="%%~i"^<nul ^| find /v " "')do set "_dns=!_dns!%%~n"

title Gateway: !_dns! & echo/!_$E![1;33m Please^^! Wait for few seconds...!_$E![0m

ping !_dns! -n 6 -w 500 | find /c "TTL" | find "6" >nul && goto %:^) || =;(
     if "!_dns!" == "172.20.0.1" 2>nul =;(echo; !_msg#001! & !_gtw#254! & echo; !_msg#002:Primary=Secondary!
        ); else 2>nul =;( echo; !_msg#001:Primary=Secondary! & !_gtw#001! & echo; !_msg#002! );=
    );= & timeout /t 00010 /nobreak >nul & echo/!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E! & goto %:^)
```

---

> *Is there a better way to do this server-side?*
>
> - Yes, if I consider the points below:

---

**1.** Your code in the question does not identify whether the current gateway is the primary gateway nor whether the change to the secondary gateway has already been made.

---

**2.** Changing the gateway from secondary to primary will never occur in case of failure of the secondary gateway.

---

**3.** Your `echo` and `netsh` commands will be executed if your primary one is in use and fails appropriately, but only in this condition of the first one being in use and a first time in the loop, after that, the second gateway will always be repeatedly configured for use even when offline.

---

**4.** The ***`%~1`*** in ***`set "str1=%~1"`*** makes no sense in your question due to the lack of citation about the argument(s) used and/or the purpose of the comparison where argument `%~1` defines a variable `str1` and in which its substring (`"%str1:"TTL="=%"`) is compared:

```
set "str1=%~1"

if not "%str1:"TTL="=%" == "%str1%"
```

---

<sub>**P.S.**From this point on, refer to the code in your [`answer...`](https://superuser.com/a/1811522/969781)</sub>

---

**5.** The items observed/pointed out in the items above **1.**, **2.** and **3.** are repeated in your actions/effects also in your current **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1811522/969781)**.

---

**6.** There is no need to create a file when redirecting your ping command with redirection, and a replacement where the output is omitted with `>nul` and the redirection to an operator `&&` (return 0), `||` (return non 0) can bring the same result without additional `ìfs`, remembering that when closing the **[bath](/questions/tagged/bath)** **[script](/questions/tagged/script)**, the created file will remain there without use.

```
ping 172.20.0.1 -n 2 > pingtest.txt
 if %errorlevel%==0 goto waiting

ping 172.20.0.1 -n 2 >nul && goto waiting
```

---

<sub>**P.S.**From this point on, refer to the version #1 of this answer</sub>

> *<s>A future edit will be made adding the action/command descriptions, but this will be done in my idle/spare time, as soon as possible.</s>*

---

**a)** Define your variables and also enable the use of substrings in this definition or your commands, enabling the relevant change to **Gateway .1** and **Gateway .254** with:

```
set "_gtw#254=netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" static 172.20.0.10 255.255.255.0 172.20.0.254"
set "_gtw#001=!_gtw#254:172.20.0.254=172.20.0.1!"
set "_msg#001=Primary Gateway NOT reachable"
set "_msg#002=Primary Data UP"
...
if "!_dns!" == "172.20.0.1" 2>nul =;(
           echo; !_msg#001!
           !_gtw#254!
           echo; !_msg#002:Primary=Secondary!
           );= else =;( 
           echo; !_msg#001:Primary=Secondary!
           !_gtw#001!
           echo; !_msg#002!
           );=
```

---

**b)** Get the output of the `netsh interface ipv4 show config` command in a `for /f` loop first, and use the appropriate token/delimiter to get the IP of the DNS/Gateway currently in use, and in a second `for /f` loop, filter/remove any spaces with `find /aVoid " " ...` :

```
for /f tokens^=2*delims^=: %%i in ('netsh interface ipv4 show config ^| findstr "DNS.*DHCP.*[0-9]"
   ')do for /f %%n in ('%ComSpec% /u /c echo="%%~i"^>nul ^| find /v " "')do set "_dns=!_dns!%%~n"
```

---

**c)** The `ping` command used will take about 10 seconds, so a title displaying the DNS/Gateway already obtained and in addition some message displayed during this time, can be used to give the user some sign that there is activity running:

[image]

```
title Gateway: !_dns!
echo/!_bs!!_$E![1;33m Please^^! Wait for few seconds...!_$E![0m
```

---

**d)** In the case of code that will operate in a **`:loop`**, from which I assume that its use is not occasional and that its execution will remain running for some time, there is no reason not to have some additional elaboration, such as color in text using **[ANSI](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)** and instead of erase the entire screen with **`cls`**, do so only on the relevant lines, in addition to keeping the screen in dimensions *"adjusted"* **[`mode`](https://ss64.com/nt/mode.html)** to the text to be displayed:

---

```
for /f tokens^=1*delims^=#skip^=4 %%i in ('echo;prompt $E#$H^|cmd.exe
    ')do set "_$E=%%~i" & set "_bs=%%~j" & mode.com con: cols=60 lines=5

:: $E set _$E [%%~i] to ESC Character 
:: $H set _bs [%%~j] to BackSpace Character

:: Display size/buffer - number of columns wide and number of lines deep:
:: MODE    CON[:] [COLS=c] [LINES=n]
:: mode.com con:   cols=60  lines=5
title >nul & ... echo/!_$E![1F!_$E![0J 
...
title Gateway: ... echo/!_$E![1;33m Please^^! Wait for few seconds...!_$E![0m
```

---

**e)** Establish a **`ping` number** (`-n 6`) and count (`find /Count`) the occurrences of **"`TTL`"** outputs using redirector `|` and omitting the outputs on screen (`>nul`), also in this command processing, make advantageous use of the operators **`&&`** and **`||`** to define relevant actions according to `return 0` and `retunr non 0`:

```
ping !_dns! -n 6 | find /c "TTL" | find "6" <nul && .. || ...

your ping cmd && (
     echo/ Retuned 0  
    )  ||  (
     echo/ Retuned non 0
    )  

ping !_dns! -n 6 -w 500 | find /c "TTL" | find "6" >nul && goto %:^)
ping !_dns! -n 6 -w 500 | find /c "TTL" | find "6" >nul || if condition() else()
```

---

**f)** Using the operator in the condition `return 0`, to return to restart `DNS/Gateway` obtainment actions, and again `ping` with `timeout` of appropriate interval, in case the "TTL" count does not match, an `if` assumes the condition to `return non 0`, and identifies the current `DNS/Gateway` assumed by composing the text and the appropriate command using the `varible:substrings=?` relevant to the condition composing the relevant text and command:

```
if "!_dns!" == "172.20.0.1" 2>nul =;(
           echo; !_msg#001!
           !_gtw#254!
           echo; !_msg#002:Primary=Secondary!
           );= else =;( 
           echo; !_msg#001:Primary=Secondary!
           !_gtw#001!
           echo; !_msg#002!
           );=
```

---

**g)** After the actions processed in the items mentioned above, the `timeout` remains for the command loop to be executed for new diagnosis and pertinent actions based on command returns, then a wait followed by the cleaning (`echo/ ESC[ANSI codes`) of the lines used and redirection to `goto` label `%:^)` that starts new loop perfect meets these actions:

```
timeout /t 00010 /nobreak >nul 
echo/!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E![1F!_$E![0J!_$E!
goto %:^)
```

---

---

Read more:

- [`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Netsh /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)
- [`Timeout /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [ANSI Escape Sequences](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)

  - [Use ANSI colors in the terminal](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-ansi.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I got a shorter way for it.
here is how..

```
@echo off

cls
:starting
ping 172.20.0.1 -n 2 > pingtest.txt

c:\windows\system32\findstr.exe "TTL=" pingtest.txt

if %errorlevel%==0 goto waiting

echo "DATA is DOWN switching to BACKUP Network"

netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" static 172.20.0.2 255.255.255.0 172.20.0.254   

timeout /t  60

:waiting

echo "DATA is working witing for delay"
timeout /t  60

goto starting
```